# Running Java Programs on the Command Prompt

Tags: java, command-prompt

I have done a lot of researching on this concept but I can't seem to run a java program on the command prompt. Let's say we had a simple program like this:

```
public class Hello_World {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

On the command prompt I tried:

```
javac Hello_World.java
```

But I get:

```
'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file
```

So I compiled it on BlueJ and then did this:

```
java Hello_World.java
```

But it said "cannot load or find main class Hello_World"!

I am currently using Windows 7, and made the programs on Notepad++ and BlueJ (to compile).
Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Make sure you have set the JAVA_HOME path pointing to your jdk dir installation and you've modified the PATH environment variable to recognize the programs in the JAVA_HOME\bin directory.

Comment: I have tried all answers and none of them worked, sorry...

Comment: You should try moving to something else...

Answer (score 3):

[This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html)  explains in detail what you have to do to set class path. Primarily you need to set your environment variables so that your shell finds the right directory containing `javac` to compile your program

Answer (score 1):

```
javac' is not recognized ..
```

comes when you haven't point your java bin directory to your path environment variable. Because bin directory is the place where javac.exe exist.

To do it.

```
1) right click on mycomputer property
2) go to Advance system settings.
3) go to environment variable.
4) In system variable click on path
5) go to edit mode and provide your path to java bin directory.
```

in my case it is `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_01\bin;`

Answer (score 0):

```
'javac' is not recognized as an internal...
```

means OS does not know where `javac` program is located. Either add it to `PATH` or run explicitly

```
 my\path\to\file\javac Hello_World.java
```

Compiling will convert `*.java` to `*.class`

`Hello_World.class` file should be located according to it's `package` directive. Since you have no one, in your case it should be located in the same directory you will run `java`.

To run your class specify it's name not file name

```
java Hello_world
```

looking for the class is essential part of launching and occurs by rules.